# How to use data() as a function argument

Tags: r

How can I write a function that takes an argument which is passed to the `data` function in R.

As a simple example

```
load_data <- function(mydata) {
    x <- data(mydata)
    x
}
```

If I tried to use this to load iris

```
load_data(mydata = "iris")
```

The function just returns "data set mydata not found"

My end goal here is to have a function that attaches a dataset to the function's environment, and then the function would do some arbitrary calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `iris` to be stored in `x` then you don't need to call `data` at all.

```
load_data <- function(mydata) {
  x <- mydata
  x
}

load_data(iris)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want `data()` to evaualte that character string, it needs to be passed via `list=`

```
load_data <- function(mydata) {
  x <- data(list=mydata)
  x
}
```

I'm not sure what you were expecting to be returned but the `?data` help page tells you it just returns the name of the data sets loaded, not the data itself.

If you only want it to load into the function scope, then also set the `environment=` parameter

```
load_data <- function(mydata) {
  data(list=mydata, environment=environment())
}
```